# Handling null returns in new linq objects c#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

What I'm going for? I need to post a newly created object to a db, the incoming object may have a null value. The created object is set to `#nullible true` where needed.

When data comes in and I land on a null string in my object I get a null reference and land on catch.

My code:

```
Objects.Data.Info.StoredData postData = new Objects.Data.Info.StoredData
                                {
                                    Name = data.data.Name,
                                    Type = data.data.Type,
                                    Price = data.data.Price,
                                    Indicator = data.data.Indicator,
                                    Scan = data.data.Scan,
                                    Comment = data.data.Extra
                                };
                                db.Information.Add(postData);
                                db.SaveChanges();
```

data.data.Extra can be null, sometimes.

I would usually write if statements to counter this, but don't feel like it's the best practice here. What direction should I go? I've checked a few other questions and msdn and can't find a clear path.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an actual problem here? You're not dereferencing `data.data.Extra` so you won't get a NRE from what you've shown. As long as `Comment` is nullable (both the property and the mapped column), this *should* be fine. If `data.data` could be null, *then* you'd have to do some testing before you access the `Extra` property (and all the others, too). What kind of problem are you expecting if `data.data.Extra` is `null`? Keep in mind that `#nullable` applies to code, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can succinctly default to an empty string when the property is null by using the `??` operator, like so:

```cs
Comment = data.data.Extra ?? ""  
//the value on the right is used if the expression on the left is null
```

`??` is called the 'null-coalescing' operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

---

If you also want to handle the intermediate properties being null (which I don't think applies to this case but is good to know), and still want to default to an empty string, you can combine this with Eugene's suggestion of using `?.` like so:

```cs
Comment = data?.data?.Extra ?? ""
```

`?.` is called the 'null-conditional' operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Null Conditional Operator (`?.`), like this:

```
data?.data?.Name
```

This will prevent an `NullReferenceException` if `data` or `data.data` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var postData = new Objects.Data.Info.StoredData
                                {
                                    Name = data.data.Name,

                                    Type = data.data.Type,
                                    Price = data.data?.Price,
                                    Indicator = data.data.Indicator,
                                    Scan = data.data.Scan,
                                    Comment = data.data.Extra
                                };
                                db.Entry(postData).State=EntityState.Added;
                                db.SaveChanges();
```

I thought that you have facing difficulty with Price attribute because this one is Not null in your db once your programming  cursor over there it failed, so once you exactly do what I did then eventually you change this nullable and then easily check or insert on runtime.

Comment: If you check your db then u find price is set to not null so I just made it possible that it not instantly return the error of null instance of object

Comment: Why u use data.data?? definitely u have one to one or one to many relationship but your linq doesn't fulfil the whole domain of your issue

Comment: U only write and write to only prove that if Wrong is ther then every where I think basic issue is there of State of Deniel which unfortunatly victim not others only u\

Comment: I ask u a question that Without having u use the Entityframework then How u able to use db.SaveChanges()???

Comment: if `data.data` is `null` (as you're checking for with `?.`) then the `Name` assignment will throw an NullReferenceException in your sample code